Nyquist stability criterion in discrete time domain
I've been transforming systems from the s-domain to the z-domain, and looking at the Nyquist plots I get in the z-domain.
So far I've assumed that the Nyquist stability criterion that applies in the s-domain applies in the z-domain.
That is, for an open loop system in the s-domain \$L(s)\$ , system stability is assessed through evaluating whether the following relation holds:
$$
 N = Z- P
$$
Where

N: number of clockwise encirclements of the Nyquist plot around the critical point \$-1 + 0j\$
P: number of non-minimum phase poles of \$L(s)\$ (i.e. on the right-hand side of the s-plane
and lying outside the unit circle in the z-plane).
Z: number of non-minimum phase zeros of \$L(s)\$ (i.e. on the right-hand side of the s-plane
and lying outside the unit circle in the z-plane).

Does then, the same approach adopted for stability analysis of systems through Nyquist plots in the s-domain apply to the z-domain (that is, assessing the expression \$N = Z-P \$).

Sampled signals will, at higher frequencies, have a significant extra delay (due to the process of sampling). That extra delay does not appear in unsampled systems.

Hi there Andy, that's something I'm aware of, but that aside, can you more or less read the Nyquist plots in the same way?
